# python csv split row value, and new column

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file,

```
    a         b              c
   text      text        2020/15 file  
   text      text        2020/12 file  
   text      text        2020/37 file  
   text      text        2020/25 file
```

i want output  (replace regex-split row value and new column),

```
    a         b              c             new column
   text      text        2020/15 file         15
   text      text        2020/12 file         12 
   text      text        2020/37 file         37
   text      text        2020/25 file         25
```

how can i do it, Please help me, Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]! [It appears no attempt was made.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: Have you make any attempt in solving the problem ?

Comment: no, because i dont know use which method, i dont want code, may be a link, i look for my problem,  but i didnt find a solved ansver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do your need. read a csv named old.csv and create new.csv in your format in the same folder.

Mark Solved , do some workouts before asking any questions here....

```
import csv,re
def find_number(text, c):
    return re.findall(r'%s(\d+)' % c, text)
col1, col2, col3, col4 = [], [], [], []
with open("Old.csv",'rt')as f: #csv file name
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
      col1.append(row[0])
      col2.append(row[1])
      col3.append(row[2])
for _ in col3:#extracting /
    col4.extend(find_number(_, "/"))

rows = zip(col1,col2,col3,col4)
with open('New.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: please accept the answer @eroniko Click Tick on the left side of code. so that everyone knows its an accepted answer